# Java HttpClient or PostMethod truncating return data to 64k

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using Apache Commons HttpClient to grab some data from a server. My problem is that the returned XML data is always truncated to the first 64k. I was hoping this might just be a case of setting a limit on the relevant object, but apparently not - or at least, I can't find any information about such a method. I'm assuming it's a client issue as the server belongs to another company and presumably serves the data fine to everyone else.

Any ideas?

My code btw is super simple:

```
protected String send(Server server, String query) throws Exception {
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(server.getUrl());
    post.setParameter("XMLString", query);
    try {
        client.executeMethod(post);
       return post.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } finally {
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

fyi, same thing happens with the following code using InputStreams rather than the getResponseBodyAsString() method.

```
protected String send(Server server, String query) throws Exception {
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(server.getUrl());
    post.setParameter("XMLString", query);
    try {
        client.executeMethod(post);
        InputStream stream = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ( (line=reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

So, do you know if there is a limit set somewhere? The fact that the String is response is *always* 64k does seem to suggest there must be. But where?!

Thanks

Alastair

Comment: How do you initialize your *HttpClient*? Have you tried the tipps from this site http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/troubleshooting.html? Have you thought about the character sets?

Comment: just good old New HttpClient().

Comment: I mean how do you construct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ERRATUM: the 64k limit is false. It as in artefact of the eclipse debugger which won't show appears the be the truncating culprit.

SOLUTION: I have now got the code working as follows:

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(server.getUrl());
    post.setParameter("XMLString", query);
    post.setRequestContentLength(PostMethod.CONTENT_LENGTH_AUTO);
    post.setStrictMode(true);
    try {
        client.executeMethod(post);
        return post.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } finally {
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
```

I'll admit I don't know *why* that works, but speculate it's something to do with the content length settings.

Separately, be aware that these methods are deprecated and I'm only using them because I'm working on a legacy system. If you are working on a more adaptable system I'd suggest following @HellGhost's advice.

Answer (score 2):

Save the ResponseBody as string and return the string, because the method `releaseConnection()` is called before returning the result.

Furthermore, you should consider whether you really want to use the library HttpClient 3.x even further, since the development has been set and it has been replaced by the library HttpComponents project in its HttpClient and HttpCore modules.
An example use for the new HttpClient:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(server.getUrl());
HttpResponse response = client.executeMethod(post);
return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: My friend, I would LOVE to update the classpath to use contemporary libraries. My company however would probably kill me as I'd no doubt take down a bunch of profitable but legacy services. :( shame.

Comment: Also, I'd like to just comment on the finally/return issue. The finally doesn't actually interrupt the execution of the return line, merely the act of returning. This is easily shown just by moving the return line down out of the try/finally block. In that case the returned value is always null because the connection has by that time been closed.

Comment: It is null because the method is released and all content is cleared. You must save the content before doing the release.